# clearTimeout() doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm trying to make a slider automatic and manual with radio buttons, but when i click on radio button 1, for example, my time doesn't reset.

For example, if i'm now on button 3, and i have only 1 second until button 4, but i click on button 1, i have only 1 second until i get on button 2.

That's what i tried to do in javascript:

```js
var bo;
var counter = 0;
function ro(){
    if(counter==0){
        bo=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked==true){
        counter=1;
        window.clearTimeout(bo);
        bo=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked==true){
        counter=2; 
        window.clearTimeout(bo);
        bo=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio3').checked==true){
        counter=3;
        window.clearTimeout(bo);
        bo=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio4').checked==true){
        counter=4;
        window.clearTimeout(bo); 
        bo=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);  
    }
    if(counter==4){
        counter=0;
    }
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked=true;
}
```

Someone told me that could be easier with jquery, but i'm trying to learn javascript, so if you can help me to resolve this in javascript, it will be awesome :)

I'm beginner, so any suggestion could help me very much. Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you clear `bo` but assign to `boss`?

Comment: It was a mistake. But it still doesn't work. I don't know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I am seeing you are using the wrong variable `bo`. Shouldn't it be `boss`? Like the following?

```js
var boss;
var counter = 0;
function ro(){
    if(counter==0){
        boss=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked==true){
        counter=1;
        window.clearTimeout(boss);
        boss=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked==true){
        counter=2; 
        window.clearTimeout(boss);
        boss=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio3').checked==true){
        counter=3;
        window.clearTimeout(boss);
        boss=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('radio4').checked==true){
        counter=4;
        window.clearTimeout(boss); 
        boss=window.setTimeout(ro, 4000);  
    }
    if(counter==4){
        counter=0;
    }
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked=true;
}
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot to correct that. But still doesn't work, i think